# How to loop through list of lists to create sum of query appearance

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I am trying to build a certain function with a csv matrix file (also converted to a list of lists for every row) with which a query should be analysed. for example:

[image: ...]
In the image, recipes will be checked for the keywords "apple" "tender" and "dish" with known appearance counts.

the list I made looks like this:

```
[['ï»¿', 'applepie', 'applecake', 'biscuit', 'bread']
['apple', 3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
['tender', 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0]
['dish', 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

For the query:
`query: ['apple', 'dish']`
it should be checked whether these appear for a dish or not. If so, it should be added to a sum of sorts. The sum for applepie whould then be 5.0. For applecake it would be 8.0 For bread it would be 0.0, etc. I would like these results in a seperate list as well.

**How should I go about constructing this loop? I have a hard time figuring out how to select the specific columns I would need.**

For python 3, thank you in advance!

expected output:
[['applepie', 'applecake', 'biscuit', 'bread']
[5.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

Comment: can you please edit your post to include what an expected output would look like, thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have edited it!

Comment: also your expected output is slightly incorrect, `'bread` will yield a value of `0` for your query

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)
 . [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. Your question is to broad please provide a [mcve] and explain why/how it is deficient.

Answer (score 0):

So it is actually much easier if you keep your data in the DataFrame. We can then use the built-in [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method on the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'applepie': [3, 2, 2], 'applecake': [4, 2, 4], 
                   'biscuit': [0, 0, 0], 'bread': [0, 1, 0]})

df.index = ['apple', 'tender', 'dish']

query = ['apple', 'dish']

results = df.loc[query].sum().to_dict()

print(results)
{'applepie': 5, 'applecake': 8, 'biscuit': 0, 'bread': 0}
```

I think the dictionary format makes more sense because it links the values to one another, or you could even keep it in the `Series` object and not convert it to a dictionary. If you are intent on having a lists of lists then you would just run the following on the `results` variable.

```
[[*results.keys()], [*results.values()]]
[['applepie', 'applecake', 'biscuit', 'bread'], [5, 8, 0, 0]]
```